# upgrading Angular 4 to Angular 5, installing packages fails

Tags: javascript, angular, forms, typescript

Node version `6.8.1` and Npm version `3.10.8`. Angular CLI version: `6.8.1`. Trying to upgrade my angular 4 to angular 5. I am not able to upgrade to Angular 5 always get the below UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY while installing the angular packages.

```
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/cdk@2.0.0-beta.12
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/common@5.2.9
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/compiler@5.2.9
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/core@5.2.9
```

**package.json**

```
    "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.9",
    "@angular/cdk": "2.0.0-beta.12",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.9",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.9",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.9",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "2.0.0-beta.9",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.9",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.9",
    "@angular/material": "2.0.0-beta.12",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.9",
    "@angular/router": "^5.2.9",
    "@swimlane/ngx-charts": "^6.0.0",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "d3": "^4.8.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "ng2-dragula": "^1.5.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
    "ts-md5": "^1.2.0",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.2.5",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
     },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.7.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.9",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.2.9",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~3.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "semver": "^5.3.0",
    "ts-node": "~3.0.4",
    "tslint": "~5.7.0",
    "typescript": "^2.4.2"
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update Package.json file for dependencies/devDependencies**

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.5.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~3.2.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.7.0",
    "typescript": "~2.4.2",    
  }
```

**Run NPM Install**

```
npm install
```

Answer (score 0):

First off all, where is an error in console?
Second, you need change versions for @angular/material and @angular/cdk,
just:

```
npm install --save @angular/material@latest @angular/cdk@latest
```

or

```
npm install --save @angular/material@5.2 @angular/cdk@5.2
```

Comment: @angular/material v2-beta is incompatible with @angular v5